# objective-c: delegate performSelectorInBackground

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, delegates, core-bluetooth

I have noticed that Corebluetooth library is running on the main thread and it seems to be freezing the UI of the viewController. In an attempt to fix this, I would like to put the CoreBluetooth delegate in a separate thread (background thread) by calling this function..

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(peripheralbackground:) withObject:_peripheral];
```

It does spawn a new thread running the selector which looks like this..

```
- (void)peripheralbackground:(CBPeripheral *)per {
    [per setDelegate:self];
    [per discoverServices:[serviceNames allKeys]];
}
```

Essentially, I would like the callbacks to be called on a separate thread other than the main UI thread. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.... thanks

UPDATE:

I have used the following within the callback; however, I am having some concurrency issues within the function block... I thought everything should be in some type of FIFO queue when we offload the work into the background thread. I can definitely see that the threads are definitely intertwining each other..

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{}

I would like to offload the work from to a background thread but run in a serial queue type of manner.

What in the world is going on :(

Comment: @CarlVeazey: However, this is not my method... this is a delegate method created by Apple......

Comment: Ah, that wasn't entirely clear. So you're saying you are already calling `peripheralbackground` via `performSelectorInBackground:` but that the delegate methods you've implemented are still being called on the main thread? If that's the case, the answer to that question should still help you. Just immediately offload the work to a background thread once you get the callback.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that tomorrow :)

Comment: I have an update on the problem. I am able to access the UI now.. but  I am currently having some concurrency issues... please check the update and thanks for the help so far ! ! !

Comment: You're better off then creating your own serial queue. Check out the concurrency guide. If that doesn't answer your question and after research on how to synchronize using GCD, then you should take what code and research you've done so far and ask a new question.